# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Occurred in Samsung Models

Tags: java, android, android-studio, noclassdeffounderror

[image]I am unable to run my app in Samsung devices.I have just updated the new version of Zxing library. But in all other phones app is working smoothly

MY build .gradle file

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

android {

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'xx.xx.xx'
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 65
    versionName '6.0.25'
    multiDexEnabled true
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

}


dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile files('libs/sun.misc.BASE64Decoder.jar')
compile files('libs/volley.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.uber.sdk:rides-android:0.5.3'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1'
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:2.0.1@aar'
compile files('libs/core-3.2.0.jar')
```

}

Comment: post your complete logcat

Comment: I have posted it..@ArunElectra

Comment: Can't you show the class name?

Comment: RegistrationActivity

Comment: This question with the given image is equivalent to you asking someone to help find something you lost, but you won't tell him what it is.

Comment: call `compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'` then `clean-rebuild` and run

Comment: AFAIU, the issue is that you are trying to instantiate a class which is not defined in the Registration Activity (line number you obscured).

It may be an API of android which Samsung removed (May be).

So, inorder to help, you should tell us what class you are trying to instantiate in the line number (61?) of RegistratioinActivity

Comment: You should post stacktraces (and other error messages) as text, not pictures.